# Can I group constants to be iterated?

Tags: perl, constants

i want to ask if there's a way to do the following.

1. have a bunch of constants in a group named, say CONST,
2. enter an array of variables, in this case lets say 3 variables in array ARRAY,
3. iterate through all 3 variables to check if they belong in CONST using say:

---

```
foreach my $var(@ARRAY){
    if(lc($var) eq CONST){
     #do something
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
foreach my $var(@ARRAY){
    if((lc($var) eq const1) or (lc($var) eq const2) or ... or (lc($var) eq constk)){
     #do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to check if each item in `@array` exists in a separate constant list. You can use `grep` to do it like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant CONST => ( 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux' );

my @array = ( 'narf', 'poit', 'baz', 'fnarf', 'QUux' );

foreach my $item( @array ) {
    print "$item is in CONST\n" if grep { $_ eq lc $item } CONST;
}
```

Output:

```
baz is in CONST 
QUux is in CONST
```

Comment: hi what does the $_refer to in this case in the last line? thanks

Comment: `$_` holds each element of the list returned by `CONST` as it is filtered through the code block in the `grep`. See [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for more on how `$_` works.

Answer (score 4):

You can store your constants in a hash:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @arr = qw(a B c);
my %const = map { $_ => 1 } qw(b d);

for my $var (@arr) {
    print "$var\n" if exists $const{lc $var};
}

__END__

B
```

Answer (score 2):

Before Perl v5.18 came out and they reclassified smart match as an experimental feature, I'd say use [smart match](http://search.cpan/org/perldoc?perlop#Smartmatch_Operator):

```
foreach my $var(@ARRAY){
    if (lc($var) ~~ [ CONST ]) {
     #do something
    }
}
```

But now I'd say listen to toolic and friedo.